# How to remove null element from int array (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, int, java-stream

I have an `int` array with elements `0`. I want to remove those elements and reduce the size of my array.

I read an example for `String` array in [Removing empty element from Array(Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935581/removing-empty-element-from-arrayjava) and apply it to my case:

```
int[] in1 = {0, 0, 2, 0, 3};
int[] in1 = Arrays.stream(in1).filter(x -> x != 0).toArray(int[]::new);
```

Unfortunately, I receive an error:

> The method `toArray()` in the type `IntStream` is not applicable for the arguments `(int[]::new)`

My questions are:

1. How can I achieve my goal?
2. Why can't I filter my `int` array the same way as a `String` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a primitive `int[]` don't supply arguments to `toArray()`:

```
in1 = Arrays.stream(in1).filter(x -> x != 0).toArray();
```

Also notice that you do not prefix `in1` with `int[]` again, since you have already defined the variable `in1`

The reason why it doesn't work the same way as the other question is because [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) returns an `IntStream` which has a version of [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--) which returns an `int[]`.

Using

```
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"This","", "will", "", "", "work"})
```

will call [`Arrays.stream(T[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-), which:

> Returns a sequential `Stream` with the specified array as its source.

Or a `Stream<String>`. Then using `toArray()` from the `Stream` class will be calling [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) version, which accepts an `IntFunction`, which will convert it to a specific type of `Array`. (The `toArray()` method that accepts no arguments from `Stream` returns an `Object[]`)

Answer (score 1):

As we know, primitive types are not object in java, for them there are overloaded `stream()`method in `Arrays` class. Suppose here just consider `int`. If we pass `int[]` then `stream(int[] array)` getting called and returns `IntStream` object.
If you go and see `IntStream` class then you will find only one `toArray`method, which doesn't accepting any arguments.

So, we can't do `toArray(int[]::new)`.

`int[] in1 = {0, 0, 2, 0, 3};
 int[] in2 = Arrays.stream(in1).filter(x -> x != 0).toArray();`

But for any Reference type array, we can convert to specific type.
e.g

```
String[] str2 = {"a","b",null,"c"};
    String[] strArr = Arrays.stream(str2).filter(i -> !=null).toArray(String[]::new);
    for (String string : strArr) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

In the Reference type case, a generic `stream` method gets called from `Arrays` class and produces `Stream<T>`, now `Stream` interface has two overloaded `toArray()`.
If we use

1. `toArray()` then yield `Object[]`, in this case we need to caste.
2. `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` then give us `A[]`, where `A` is any reference type.

See below example

```
package test;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class EliminateZeroFromIntArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] in1 = {0, 0, 2, 0, 3};
    int[] in2 = Arrays.stream(in1).filter(x -> x != 0).toArray();
    for (int i : in2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    String[] str = {"a","b",null,"c"};
    Object[] array = Arrays.stream(str).filter(i -> i !=null).toArray();

    for (Object object : array) {
        System.out.println((String)object);
    }

    String[] str2 = {"a","b",null,"c"};
    String[] strArr = Arrays.stream(str2).filter(i -> i !=null).toArray(String[]::new);
    for (String string : strArr) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best version of this you'll find but:

```
private int[] removeZeros(int[] array, int toRemove)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int arrayLength = array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == toRemove)
                count++;
        }

        int[] newArray = new int[arrayLength - count];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] != toRemove)
            {
                newArray[j] = array[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```